# Please help me create this diagram in LaTeX

Tags: diagrams

Could someone please show me how to make this diagram using LaTeX? I have no idea where to begin with something like this.

Thank you so much for your help!!

[image: club distances]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Answer (score 5):

Something like this:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,border=3mm,tikz,preview]{standalone}
    \usetikzlibrary{positioning,%
                    }
    \usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance=7mm and 22mm,
                        ]
\coordinate (c1) at (0,0);
\foreach[count=\xi from 1] \i in {2,3,...,9}
    \coordinate[below=of c\xi] (c\i);
\draw[thick,shorten >=-1mm]  (c1) -- (c9);
%
\foreach[count=\xj from 1] \j in {2,4,6,8}
{
    \node (a\xj) [left=of c\j] {$\pmb{Dist}_{j=\xj}$};
    \draw[thick,dashed]   (a\xj) -- (c\j);
}
%
\node (b1) [right=of c1] {$Dist_{j=1}^{\max}$};
    \draw[dashed] (b1) -- (c1);
    \draw[dashed] (c2) -- (c2 -| b1.west);
\foreach \k in {3,5,7}
{
    \node (b\k) [right=of c\k] {$(Dist_{j=1}^{\max}),(Dist_{j=2}^{\max})$};
    \draw[dashed] (b\k) -- (c\k);
}
    \draw[dashed] (c9) -- (c9 -| b7.west);
%
\draw[<->,transform canvas={xshift=-7mm}]  
    (c2) -- node[left] {10 yards} (c4);
\draw[<->,transform canvas={xshift=7mm}]
    (c1) -- node[right] {5 yards} (c2);
\draw[<->,transform canvas={xshift=7mm}]
    (c2) -- node[right] {5 yards} (c3);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```